# WatiN read attribute from iframe's body

Tags: c#, attributes, frame, watin

Is there a way to read the `style` attribute of `body` inside an `iFrame`?
I've tried using multiple combinations of `Body`, `NativeElement`, `Frame` and other `Properties`, but so far I had no luck.

```
    <iframe id="iFrame" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" src="some source">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
            </head>
            <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;height:500px;">
            </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
```

Example:

```cs
_browser.Frame(Find.ById(frameId)).Body.GetAttributeValue("style")
```

Comment: Did you tried: _browser.Frame(Find.ById(frameId)).Body.Style;

Answer (score 0):

Iframe may be inside a different form, did you tried?

it happend once to me, the iframe was in a different form(nested form)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to that code and I cannot reproduce the context of the webpage that could have the iFrame, so I cannot try the solution. Thanks for pointing it out, surely I'll keep it in mind if it happens again.